# Netstat speed on windows

Tags: windows, netstat

This is more my curiosity bugging me than anything else, but when I type:

```
`netstat -a`
```

the results can take as long as a minute to display.  It seems like I'm waiting forever.

However, if I type:

```
`netstat -aon`
```

the results are displayed literally instantly.

This is on Windows 7, but memory dictates that it was this way on *XP* as well.

It seems counter-intuitive since the second command actually produces more information.  Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 -n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
```

Which means no DNS queries = instant output.

Comment: Of course.  Somehow that piece of the help text was invisible to me.

Comment: same reason why netstat -ab is much faster than netstat -aon. thanks!